# Selenium macro not running properly anymore (in Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, webdriver

For over a year, I've been happily using Selenium code in an Excel document. In the last few weeks, it stopped working, it opens the browser but doesn't open the webpage. The code triggers an application error and aborts. It's not the same error but it's pretty much the same behaviour regardless of whether I use chrome, Firefox or IE.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Dim driver As New Selenium.WebDriver
driver.Start "firefox", "http://google.com"
```

Or...

```
Dim driver As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
driver.Start
```

Anybody can help me debug this annoying behaviour?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Usually when the browser opens but never navigates to the page that indicates that the driver is not in sync with the browser version. Make sure you have the most recent driver and your browser versions are all up-to-date.

Comment: Hi @JeffC, thanks for your help here.

In C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\CHANGELOG.txt, I see I have v2.0.9.0  (2016/03/02)
I feel like a total *noob* but I'm actually rather confused about how to proprely install Selenium for Excel VBA. There doesn't seem to be much help on that on seleniumhq.org
I followed instructions here
https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/
And apparently v2.0.9.0 is the latest version (though it was released in March)
I've got the latest version of Chrome
Version 54.0.2840.99 m

Any other suggestions ... ? Thanks so much.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. I've never used Selenium for Excel VBA. I've only used Java and C#. If you aren't getting any error message, I would say that you have it installed properly but as I mentioned before, this behavior generally indicates that the driver and browser version aren't matching up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I figured it out, thanks to this link:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/128
Managed to download the latest version of the *Chrome Driver*
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/

Looks like there's no equivalent fix for Firefox, have to roll back to version 46. Hopefully an update will be released, but in the meantime, I'm so very happy to have at least one browser working again.

Cheers guys.